# conditionally dividing columns in dataframes based in values pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So i have a dataframe that looks like this...let's call it df1

```
  Disease  Gene1  Gene2  Gene3  Gene4
0      D1      1      1     26      1
1      D2      1      1      1      1
2      D3      1     18      1     17
3      D4     25      1      1      1
4      D5      1      1      1      1
5      D6      1     33      1     12
6      D7      1      1      1      1
7      D8      5      1      1      1
```

And another that looks like...df2:

```
    Disease Counts
0   D1  117
1   D2  224
2   D3  411
3   D4  180
4   D5  96
5   D6  24
6   D7  331
7   D8  512
```

I need to divide the row in df1 by the count in df2 based on the Disease column matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the indices to 'Disease' for both dfs then you can call [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html#pandas.DataFrame.div):

```
In [127]:
df.set_index('Disease').div(df1.set_index('Disease')['Counts'], axis=0)

Out[127]:
            Gene1     Gene2     Gene3     Gene4
Disease                                        
D1       0.008547  0.008547  0.222222  0.008547
D2       0.004464  0.004464  0.004464  0.004464
D3       0.002433  0.043796  0.002433  0.041363
D4       0.138889  0.005556  0.005556  0.005556
D5       0.010417  0.010417  0.010417  0.010417
D6       0.041667  1.375000  0.041667  0.500000
D7       0.003021  0.003021  0.003021  0.003021
D8       0.009766  0.001953  0.001953  0.001953
```

By setting the index to 'Disease' the dfs will align on the index values

You can then call [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) to restore the the column:

```
In [132]:
(df.set_index('Disease').div(df1.set_index('Disease')['Counts'], axis=0)).reset_index()

Out[132]:
  Disease     Gene1     Gene2     Gene3     Gene4
0      D1  0.008547  0.008547  0.222222  0.008547
1      D2  0.004464  0.004464  0.004464  0.004464
2      D3  0.002433  0.043796  0.002433  0.041363
3      D4  0.138889  0.005556  0.005556  0.005556
4      D5  0.010417  0.010417  0.010417  0.010417
5      D6  0.041667  1.375000  0.041667  0.500000
6      D7  0.003021  0.003021  0.003021  0.003021
7      D8  0.009766  0.001953  0.001953  0.001953
```

Comment: Not sure what i did wront but i got a key error: KeyError: 'Disease'...I previously set the column indexes using df.set_index('Disease, inplace=True). I dont know if that would cause any problems.

Comment: If the 'Disease' column is already the index you don't need to set it again